# Oracle: Display row number with 'order by' clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder how could i print a row number for sql statement where is using order. 
Currently i tried `ROWNUM` but as i understand it works only for unsorted result set.

```
SELECT rownum, a.lg_id, a.full_name, a.sort_order
  FROM activity_type_lang a
  where a.lg_id = 'en'
  order by a.full_name;
```

TIA

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In addition to nesting the query, you can use an analytic function

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.full_name),
       lg_id,
       full_name,
       sort_order
  FROM activity_type_lang a
 WHERE a.lg_id = 'en'
 ORDER BY a.full_name
```

Using analytic functions also makes it easier if you want to change how ties are handled.  You can replace `ROW_NUMBER` with RANK or `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: It worked for me. Looks neater than nested queries. However, just one question - Does this analytic function also calls the query via nesting to assign rownums? Will it have similar performance ?

Answer (score 7):

Oh. Seems i've found already a solution.

```
    Select rownum, lg_id, full_name, sort_order from 
(SELECT a.lg_id, a.full_name, a.sort_order
      FROM activity_type_lang a
      where a.lg_id = 'en'
      order by a.full_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

rownum is applied before ordering, so you have to rewrite your query like this:
select rownum, xxx.* from (
SELECT a.lg_id, a.full_name, a.sort_order
  FROM activity_type_lang a
  where a.lg_id = 'en'
  order by a.full_name
) xxx;

Answer (score 2):

> Hello. I wonder how could i print a
>   row number for sql statement where is
>   using order. Currently i tried ROWNUM
>   but as i understand it works only for
>   unsorted result set.

To be clear (somebody might get it wrong). It **does** work (but not in the way you expect). The problem with it is that it "attaches" the ROWNUM **before the sort** and you get your records but not in consecutive ROWNUM records. Why? Because

> The first record that meets the where
>   criteria in a select statement is
>   given rownum=1

This is really good example how select / order mechanism works.