# Rownum from a select of multiple table

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I'd like to have a column ROWNUM in my result when I select from multiple tables.
Is this possible? How can I do that?

My query is something like :

```
select rownum, xx,zzz,aaa,aaa  
from table1, table2, table3  
where condition1  
     and condition2  
     and condition3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: Display row number with 'order by' clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377825/oracle-display-row-number-with-order-by-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible .
use the T-SQL ROW_NUMBER function.

[As described here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Otherwise you can achive this , without using the function like here :
[sql-rownum-how-to-return-rows-between-a-specific-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552769/sql-rownum-how-to-return-rows-between-a-specific-range)

Comment: Hi I am using oracle .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377825/oracle-display-row-number-with-order-by-clause